# Grid Header Mouse up event - WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF  DataGrid and I have subscribed to the PreviewMouseUp event of the Grid. Now since the grid contains records and column headers, I can click either of them and the PreviewMoudeUp event will get triggered. How do I know whether I clicked the column Header or clicked the Row? Basically I want to get the exact control (either column header or the content row) within the grid.

When I look at the sender, it always gives a reference to the Grid. But actually I want to know within the grid a reference to the header or row whichever is clicked and I need this information in the PreviewMouseUp event. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Indira

Answer (score 0):

You check the [OriginalSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx) property of the event args.

Comment: But the problem is that even the OriginalSource property points to the Grid. Actually I want the Header reference on which the MouseUp occurred.

Comment: OriginalSource will give you the actual control being clicked. Suppose you click a cell, that cell will have a template. Let's say it's a TextBlock, OriginalSource will be that TextBlock. All you have to do is navigate the visual tree up until you find a DataGridRow (row was clicked) or a DataGridColumnHeader (a column was clicked).

Comment: Thanks..will explore that route.